# Inserting and deleting information, SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working with this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ and author created methods : addContact and deleteContact. I understood how I can add contact: `database.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));` but how can I delete that contact? Somebody please help me!

addContact:

```
void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

deleteContact:

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Er, you call the `deleteContact` method. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @cl I don't understand which argument should I use

Comment: How do you know *which* contact to delete, if you don't have an object?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public int DeleteRow() {
//Delete from table where name=Ravi
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String wherearegs[] = {"Ravi"};
    int count = db.delete(TableName, Column_Name + "=?", wherearegs);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it !!!

This is method Delete single contact.

```
public static void delete(int rowID) {
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(TABLE_ARTICLE, KEY_ID + " =? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(rowID)});
}
```

This is method Delete all contact

```
 public static void deleteAll() {
    String sql = "DELETE FROM " + YOUR_NAME_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL(sql);

}
```